# D language: I can't split a text block copied from a Wikipedia unicode chart into a list of single-letter strings. Output comes out wrong in editor

Tags: unicode, split, character-encoding, format, d

The MWE and the only code you need to see this is the following:

```
module unicode_support;

import std.string;

const wstring unicodeVarSource = `
                              
                              
                              
                              
                              
                                
                              
                              
                              
                                
                                    
                                  
                                
                              
                              
                              
                                    
                                  
                              
                                
                                      
                                
                              
                              
                              
                              
                              
                              
                              
                              
                              
                              
                              
                              
                              
                              
                              
                              
                              
                              
                              
                              
                                  
                              
                              
                              
                              
                              
                              
                        ϐ   ϑ   ϒ   ϕ   
ϰ   ϱ   ϴ   ϵ   ϶         
                              
                              
                              
                              
                              
                              
                              
                              
                              
                              
                      `;

const bool[wstring] unicodeVars;

//import std.stdio;
import std.file;

static this() {
   auto letters = unicodeVarSource.split();
   
   write("debug_output.txt", letters);
   
}
```

Firstly, Visual D's debug console has an issue with displaying Unicode, so I thought we'd better output to file.  Well, after running, open up `debug_output.txt` in something like Notepad++ and go to Encoding > Utf-8.  The output format is all wrong - and it doesn't display a single character that you can see in the source file.

What I need is to split the source string into individual letters given the source format as is, because that's exactly how I get the data (copy / pasted from the browser).

I'm then going to put each letter in a AA entry so that I can determine if a given char in another string is a what my software will consider a variable or not.

Comment: I tried replacing the long string with simply the first few letters separated by real spaces in the source file.  Same issue, format is not right.  Is this a bug in D?

Comment: your input is a `wstring` (UTF-16), using `.split` on it produces a `wstring[]`. The `write` function from std.file dumps raw memory (casts to `void[]`) into the file. I don't know what exactly the layout is with dumping a `wstring[]` (looks a bit confusing, might even be undefined how that looks?) but when you use std.conv's `.to!string` you can see the array as nice D array syntax in UTF8 and see that the array has the correct data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not writing what you think you're writing to the file. Your variable `letters` is a `wstring[]` - an array of wstrings. Let's look at the actual bytes in `debug_output.txt`:

[image]

You're right - this looks nothing like the characters you're trying to write. That's because these are [slices](https://dlang.org/articles/d-array-article.html) - simple length/ptr pairs. I ran this in 32-bit mode, so I get a 4-byte length (`02 00 00 00`) followed by a 4-byte pointer (`A2 A2 48 00`). These point to memory in your application as it is running. I would say that this should not generally be what D does - it's confusing to the user, as evinced by this post.

If you want to write this array to file, consider using [`std.conv.to`](https://dlang.org/library/std/conv/to.html):

```
    import std.conv : to;
    write("debug_output.txt", letters.to!string);
```

This will give you a file with all the symbols.

As for unicode output in the console, on Windows, there's the function `SetConsoleOutputCP`, which sets the code page for the console, and enables unicode output. [More details on Adam D. Ruppe's site](http://dpldocs.info/this-week-in-d/Blog.Posted_2019_11_25.html). I'm not sure what, if anything, can be done to VisualD's console to make it print better.

Comment: Hey I spoke too soon.  That does indeed display them properly in my text editor!  Thank you!

Comment: that old post of mine sucks there;s a better way: using the native Windows functions http://dpldocs.info/this-week-in-d/Blog.Posted_2019_11_25.html

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe Thanks, updated link to go there.